# Pandas Input/output error?

Tags: pandas

I created a multiindex .h5 file and use HDFStore to store the data. However, when I try to read the dataframe from the file, it turns out that I can read some dataframes successfully but fail to read several others. The following is the error message I get:

HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.9) thread 0:
  #000: H5Dio.c line 174 in H5Dread(): can't read data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Read failed

#001: H5Dio.c line 449 in H5D_read(): can't read data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Read failed

#002: H5Dcontig.c line 560 in H5D_contig_read(): contiguous read failed
    major: Dataset
    minor: Read failed

#003: H5Dselect.c line 275 in H5D_select_read(): read error
    major: Dataspace
    minor: Read failed

#004: H5Dselect.c line 210 in H5D_select_io(): read error
    major: Dataspace
    minor: Read failed

#005: H5Dcontig.c line 890 in H5D_contig_readvv(): can't perform vectorized sieve buffer read
    major: Dataset
    minor: Can't operate on object

#006: H5V.c line 1457 in H5V_opvv(): can't perform operation
    major: Internal error (too specific to document in detail)
    minor: Can't operate on object

#007: H5Dcontig.c line 691 in H5D_contig_readvv_sieve_cb(): block read failed
    major: Dataset
    minor: Read failed

#008: H5Fio.c line 113 in H5F_block_read(): read through metadata accumulator failed
    major: Low-level I/O
    minor: Read failed

#009: H5Faccum.c line 254 in H5F_accum_read(): driver read request failed
    major: Low-level I/O
    minor: Read failed

#010: H5FDint.c line 142 in H5FD_read(): driver read request failed
    major: Virtual File Layer
    minor: Read failed

#011: H5FDsec2.c line 753 in H5FD_sec2_read(): file read failed: time = Wed Jul  3 14:07:31 2013

, filename = 'N.h5', file descriptor = 3, errno = 5, error message = 'Input/output error', buf = 0x7f8807fccb6c, size = 649492, offset = 185876480

```
major: Low-level I/O

minor: Read failed
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "/usr/share/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 165, in **getitem**

```
return self.get(key)
```

File "/usr/share/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 261, in get

```
return self._read_group(group)
```

File "/usr/share/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 651, in _read_group
    return handler(group, where)

File "/usr/share/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 400, in _read_frame
    return DataFrame(self._read_block_manager(group))

File "/usr/share/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 426, in _read_block_manager
    ax = self._read_index(group, 'axis%d' % i)

File "/usr/share/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 487, in _read_index
    _, index = self._read_index_node(getattr(group, key))

File "/usr/share/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 532, in _read_index_node
    data = node[:]

File "/usr/share/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/array.py", line 684, in **getitem**
    arr = self._readSlice(startl, stopl, stepl, shape)

File "/usr/share/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/array.py", line 781, in _readSlice
    self._g_readSlice(startl, stopl, stepl, nparr)

File "hdf5Extension.pyx", line 1092, in tables.hdf5Extension.Array._g_readSlice (tables/hdf5Extension.c:9570)
tables.exceptions.HDF5ExtError: Problems reading the array data.

Can anyone help with this problem ? Thank you so much.

Comment: pls show some complete code that you used to generate the HDFStore

Answer (score 0):

The `HDF5` file is corrupt. You can get this to occur by doing a write, then interrupting it in the middle (ctrl-c). You will be unable to recover. `HDF5` writes in chunks and if a chunk is interrupted I believe state is not consistent.

You will also get corruption if you are doing concurrent writes (either threads or processes). see this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#notes-caveats

Comment: Thank you Jeff. What I did is using HDFStore to open an HDF5 file and write a dataframe to the file, close it and loop this process. I am wondering whether or not this would corrupt the file ? Another one is that I use several processors, but I do use each processor to write in a different HDF5 file. Really thank you for your reply.

Comment: different processors to different files should be ok

Comment: on the single file should be fine too; write it once and make sure it's ok, see where it gives u an error

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. BTW, the weird thing is that even producing two files with exact the same data, the error chunks appear in different places.

Comment: if I can post your code or a link to the data (send private if u want) - I can take a look

Comment: can I send it privately to u and how can I sent it ? thank you for your help

Comment: send me a link to your data (dropbox or many sites allow this), and your code to: jeff@reback.net (need everything, how you are reading in and writing...etc)....try to make as minimally reproducable as possible..thxs

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it sounds like the HDF5 library may not be compiled with the thread-safe configure option enabled (--enable-threadsafe).  Also, if you are writing to the same file simultaneously from different processes, that is not going to work - you will need to close the file and re-open it from the other process.

See the HDF5 FAQ here:
http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf5-quest.html#gconc